# apache nutch dir is created, but result is empty

Tags: apache, web, solr, web-crawler, nutch

my output is as follows..no error and no result....
$ ./crawl urls -dir crawl -depth 3 -topN 5
cygpath: can't convert empty path
Injector: starting at 2014-05-15 09:25:20
Injector: crawlDb: -dir/crawldb
Injector: urlDir: urls
Injector: Converting injected urls to crawl db entries.
Patch for HADOOP-7682: Instantiating workaround file system
Injector: total number of urls rejected by filters: 1
Injector: total number of urls injected after normalization and filtering: 0
Injector: Merging injected urls into crawl db.
Injector: overwrite: false
Injector: update: false
Injector: finished at 2014-05-15 09:25:23, elapsed: 00:00:03

Comment: possible duplicate of [nutch crawling stops after injector.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23676969/nutch-crawling-stops-after-injector)

Comment: Set all the logs in debug mode and see what error your get. Remove the crawl directory and try again with the above command that you have mentioned.