# nutch crawling stops after injector.

Tags: apache, web, generator, nutch, web-crawler

here is my cygwin screen looks...

```
cygpath: can't convert empty path
Injector: starting at 2014-05-15 16:57:50
Injector: crawlDb: -dir/crawldb
Injector: urlDir: urls
Injector: Converting injected urls to crawl db entries.
Patch for HADOOP-7682: Instantiating workaround file system
Injector: total number of urls rejected by filters: 1
Injector: total number of urls injected after normalization and filtering: 0
Injector: Merging injected urls into crawl db.
Injector: overwrite: false
Injector: update: false
Injector: finished at 2014-05-15 16:57:52, elapsed: 00:00:02
```

Comment: could anyone say me, why injected URL is empty, eventhough URL  is given in urls folder for crawling..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Total number of urls injected is 0. That is nothing to crawl.

```
Injector: total number of urls rejected by filters: 1
Injector: total number of urls injected after normalization and filtering: 0
```

Comment: i have mentioned my URL inside the urls folder.i gave my url in reges-urlfilter.txt, which is as follows..                         # accept anything else
+^http://([a-z0-9]*/.)*http://google.com/
+^http://\s*/
and gave proxy setting in nutch-site.xml.

Comment: i have mentioned my URL inside the urls folder.i gave my url in reges-urlfilter.txt, which is as follows..                         # accept anything else
+^http://([a-z0-9]*/.)*http://google.com/   but why urls injected is 0... i am new to nutch... plz say me do i want to anything else...
+^http://\s*/
and gave proxy setting in nutch-site.xml.

Comment: What is the url you added in the folder?